# Import Image Module error while generating qrcode

Tags: python-3.x, qr-code

I installed qrcode 7.3.1 and Image 1.5.33. Pillow 9.0.0 is also installed during Image install. But while running following example from qrcode documentation

```
import qrcode
img = qrcode.make('Some data here')
type(img)  # qrcode.image.pil.PilImage
img.save("some_file.png")
```

Following error generates

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\****\venv\lib\site-packages\qrcode\image\pil.py", line 5, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
  File "C:\****\venv\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 30, in <module>
    import logging
  File "C:\****\himal\anaconda3\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sys, os, time, io, re, traceback, warnings, weakref, collections.abc
  File "C:\****\anaconda3\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in <module>
    import linecache
  File "C:\****\anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in <module>
    import tokenize
  File "c:\users\himal\anaconda3\lib\tokenize.py", line 35, in <module>
    from token import EXACT_TOKEN_TYPES
ImportError: cannot import name 'EXACT_TOKEN_TYPES' from 'token' (***\token.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\****\scan_qrcode.py", line 2, in <module>
    img = qrcode.make('Some data here')
  File "C:\****\venv\lib\site-packages\qrcode\main.py", line 13, in make
    return qr.make_image()
  File "C:\****\venv\lib\site-packages\qrcode\main.py", line 296, in make_image
    from qrcode.image.pil import PilImage
  File "C:\****\venv\lib\site-packages\qrcode\image\pil.py", line 7, in <module>
    import Image
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'
```

Python 3.8 is current python version.

Comment: I think You are missing `PIL` library. try to install it first and then rerun the code.
`pip install pillow`

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL
Such error while installing PIL at first

Comment: Such error while installing PIL at first, so I installed Pillow and qrcode and again such error comes for Image No module named

Comment: what command are you using to install `PIL` ?

Comment: pip install PIL

Comment: instead `PIL` use `pillow` whole command `pip install pillow`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240890/discussion-between-himal-acharya-and-giorgi-imerlishvili).